# Android showing remaining time is different between devices

Tags: android, time, simpledateformat

I'm developing an Android app which terminates itself after a certain amount of time. I added a button to the actionbar and it's supposed to show remaining time to the user. Here's the code:

```
String srt = getResources().getString(R.string.remainingTime) + " ";
DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

long gt = timeKeeper.getTimeUntilTermination() - timeKeeper.getElapsedTime(); // gotten from elsewhere
long ct = System.currentTimeMillis() - countdownStartedAt;
Date rt = new Date(gt - ct); // remaining time

showToast(srt + fmt.format(rt));
```

While testing it on AVD, the toast contains proper remaining time (like "00:44:32"), but on a phone the toast says "01:44:32" for some weird reason (and just to be more confusing, the app still terminates itself after 00:44:32 - the additional hour is only shown in the toast). How is it possible that the same piece of code generates different results depending on whether it's an emulator or a phone?

The class containing time variables (simplified):

```
public class TimeKeeper
{
    private long timeUntilTermination;
    private long elapsedTime;

    public long getTimeUntilTermination() {return timeUntilTermination;}
    public long getElapsedTime() {return elapsedTime;}
}
```

The Activity has a static TimeKeeper object and a method:

```
public void startTimeCountDown()
{       
    timeHandler = new Handler();
    timeHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        // terminating
    }, timeKeeper.getTimeUntilTermination() - timeKeeper.getElapsedTime());

    countdownStartedAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

They both work like they're supposed to. It's just the notification that's wrong.

timeUntiltermination variable is set in this method:

```
private void setTimeUnilTermination()
{
    long tut = (timePicker.getCurrentHour() * 3600000) +
        (timePicker.getCurrentMinute() * 60000);
    timeKeeper.setTimeUntilTermination(tut);
}
```

And the method used in auto-save, so if the user quits and restarts the app, the timer restarts from where it stopped. The elapsed time is saved to a file and then read back. No modifications.

```
private void keepElapsedTimeJustInCase() {
    timeKeeper.setElapsedTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - countdownStartedAt);
}
```

Comment: it would help if you add what your methods do (getTimeUntilTermination, getElapsedTime) and your countdownStartedAt variable. Keep in mind that System.currentTimeMillis should not be used for elapsed time measurements (use nanoTime instead)

Comment: The funny thing is that every other time-related action in my code works just fine. Only this code shows wrong time for a reason I don't understand. Everything is so random with Android.

Comment: the values of timeUntiltermination and elapsedTime are values that you set? or where do those come from? I can see that countdownStartedAt its from System. currentTimeMillis but the others give no idea what the values are.

Comment: Everything should be clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nowTime.
And this could be different in other phones, because need to be configured.